# How to create/populate a SQLITE table from JOIN command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to join two tables on a column and then populate a new table with the query results.

I know that the join command gives me the table data I want but now how do I insert this data into a new table without having to loop through the results as there are many unique column names. Is there a way to do this with a SQLite command? To do this without SQLite command would require nested for loops and become computationally expensive (if it even works).

Join command that works:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("database1.db")
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'database1.db' AS db_1")
c.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'database2.db' AS db_2")
c.execute("SELECT * FROM db_1.Table1Name AS a JOIN db_2.Table2Name AS b WHERE a.Column1 = b.Column2")
```

Attempt to join and insert command that does not error but does not populate the table:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO 'NewTableName' SELECT * FROM db_1.Table1Name AS a JOIN db_2.Table2Name AS b WHERE a.Column1 = b.Column2")
```

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes around the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sql part is:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
  SELECT expressions
  FROM existing_tables
  [WHERE conditions];
```